# Returning variable keys via public static function within a class

Tags: php, function, class

I've been having a bit of trouble doing, what I believe is possible (although I'm not sure). What I do know is that what I'm attempting to do is a bit nonsensical and not the best way to do it.

```
class myClass {
    public static function myData() {
        $data = [
            'index' => 'key'
        ];
    }
}
```

What I'm attempting to do is to return the value of `key` via static function. I've been trying to view (via `var_dump()`) what's inside of my static function (`myClass::myData();`) however, it comes up `NULL`.

I'm still pretty new to PHP, but I've been working around trying to find things to work on (even if they're pretty nonsensical) to get better acquainted. If this is at all possible, I'd like to complete it this way. I've been searching for an answer to this for about 2 hours, so yes, I have looked around to try and fix this issue myself first, but to no avail.

Additionally, if this simply can't be done, what is the best way to do something like this? I appreciate any responses!

**EDIT:** Obviously I feel a bit foolish for not returning my data at the end of my function. Now when the class is dumped (via `var_dump()`), the information in my function is returned, however, I'm still not able to selectively return the data:

```
class myClass {
    public static function myData() {
        $data = [
            'index' => 'key',
            'index1' => 'key1'
        ];
    return $data;
    }
}

myClass::myData(); //here
```

I know the information is contained in the public static function, however, how would I selectively return `key1` from `index1`

I really appreciate the help, everyone!

**EDIT 2:** I was able to figure it out with all of your help. Just a note, the example I'm using here, is obviously not the code I'm working with. The semicolon was a simple mistake, and is not in my actual code.

Here's the final product:

```
class myClass {
    public static function myData() {
        $d = [
            'index' => 'key',
            'index1' => 'key1'
        ];
    return $data;
    }
}

$data = myClass::myData();
print $data['index1']; // prints key1
```

Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm a little confused. You say you want to return the value of 'key', but 'key' is the value of the key 'index'.

Comment: If you want to return anything from a function/method; then you need a return statement in that function/method: `class myClass {
    public static function myData() {
        $data = [
            'index' => 'key';
        ]; return $data;
    }
}`

Comment: Do you want to return the entire array? the key? or the value?

Comment: Basically you need to have a 'return $data' at the end of your function.

Comment: has no one else spotted the syntax error within the array construct?

Comment: @DarylGill: You mean the semi-colon after `'key'`? :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat Perhaps this will shake your brain: `syntax error, unexpected ';'`

Comment: @DarylGill: Yeah, I didn't notice that the first time...

Comment: The new syntax for arrays still throws me off that's why I didn't notice the syntax error.

Comment: Since your edit: `return $data['index1'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a return within your function you also have a syntax error within your array construct.

```
class myClass {
    public static function myData() {
        $data = [
            'index' => 'key'; // The closing semi-colon is not necessary within the array 
        ];
    }
}
```

and to create a return:

```
return $data; // This will return the entire array 

return $data['index']; // This will return a value of *key*
```

So, If i wanted to return the entire array:

```
class myClass {
    public static function myData() {
        $data = [
            'index' => 'key'
        ];
        return $data;
    }
}
print_r(myClass::myData());
```

Answer (score 0):

your function doesn't return anything, so try :

```
return $data;
```

A function can return data, but "data inside a function" have no sense.